# order by clause in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to fetch the database data by descending order of posted date.Database containing a field named as posted_date. This is my code(in model) for fetch the data.

```
    public function get_data_by_volunteer_id($fields = "*", $volunteer_id)
{
    $this->db->select($fields);
    $query = $this->db->get_where(self::$tbl_name, array(
        "user_id" => $volunteer_id));
    return( $query->result() );
}
```

Comment: First change the question Title then tell us your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
function get_data_by_volunteer_id($fields, $volunteer_id)
{

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE user_id = '$volunteer_id' ORDER BY posted_date DESC");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following in your query

```
 $this->order_by('posted_date', 'desc');
```

So your final query would be

```
$this->db->select($fields);
$this->db->get_where(self::$tbl_name, array(
    "user_id" => $volunteer_id));
$this->order_by('posted_date', 'desc'); 
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Volunteer_notes::order_by().. i got this error message

Comment: Refer codeigniter's reference guide for details https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select ->  $this->db->order_by();